# how to display data from database to input form in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

*I want to display the data from the database to the input-form, I tried to search but it shows to me to tables
how can I fix this... the error always shows to the line of foreach, it says undefined variable and invalid argument supplied

thank you.....*

The Model

```
class Profile_model extends CI_Model {

   public function fetch_data(){
      $query = $this->db->get("tbl_admin"); //select * from tbl_admin
      return $query;
   }

}
```

The Controller

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('profile_model');
        $data["fetch_data"] = $this->profile_model->fetch_data();
        $this->load->view('bootstrap/dashboard/settings_modal', $data);
    }

}
```

The view

```
<?php foreach ($fetch_data as $value) { 
            $username = $value['username'];
            $email = $value['email'];
            $contact = $value['contact'];
            $password = $value['password'];?>

      <?php $attributes = array('id'=>'login_form1', 'class'=>'form'); ?>
      <?php echo form_open('profile', $attributes); ?>
      
        <div class="form-group text-left">
          <label> Username </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value['username']; ?>" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group text-left">
          <label> Email </label>
          <input type="Email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value['email']; ?>" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group text-left">
          <label> Contact Number</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value['contact']; ?>" placeholder="Enter Contact Number" name="username" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group text-left">
          <label> Password </label>
          <input type="Password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value['password']; ?>" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group text-left">
          <label> Confirm Password </label>
          <input type="Password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value['password']; ?>" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm" required>
        </div>
        
        <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="button">Submit</button>
      <?php echo form_close(); ?>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: you need to set a 'value' for your input field, please read this example: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#re-populating-the-form

Comment: im newbie here so didn't know much how to post ...sorry

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value->username; ?>">

Comment: i tried it but still undefined variable: $fetch_data

Comment: @LINTOTOM i was thinking it is because I'm inside a session ?

Comment: @polk can you solved this problem or not?

Comment: @KUMAR not yet maybe because it is inside the modal body

Answer (score 1):

> $fetch_data is only query now you have to fetch data using result or row function

```
<?php
 foreach($fetch_data->result() as $value)
 {
  $username = $value->username;
   //bla bla
   }?>
```

Comment: it didn't work, it gives me an error result() null and undefined $fetch_data